# Clone failed: missing OAuth configuration (GitLab, PhpStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, oauth, gitlab, phpstorm, git-clone

After deactivating my antivirus I could clone repositories without problem, but I have a problem with private ones. When cloning and setting up my credentials they're not accepted and I get the following message:

> Clone failed, warning: missing OAuth configuration for...

[image]

I’ve checked with the administrator and he says all is working from his side.

What could be the problem? Do I need to go through all the OAuth process? The administrator said that it is not necessary and has something to do with my computer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use some 3rd party GitLab-related plugin?
Do you have "Use credential helper" enabled under File | Settings | Version Control | Git?
How do you enter your credentials? If IDE prompts you to enter credentials use Username/Token pair (enter token in password field)
Perhaps, the token that you are using doesn't sufficient privileges for a push